# Generate a custom JSON Schema in JAVA using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema, jackson-modules

I'm new to this and struggling for the use cases when a POJO/Bean has nested parameters in it.

**Requirement** -

Generate a JSON schema using Jackson(latest versions are OK) for a JAVA Bean/POJO class, such that it includes the structure of nested Objects properly and also want to add custom attributes to the nested pojos(in my case, want to add a fully classified classname attribute for each nested POJO parameter).

**Use Case** -

Say, I've a Person class which is as follows. And I'm using this Person as parameter to my some operation.-

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String id;
    private int i;
    private Person2 p;
    private List<String> strList;
    private HashMap<String, String> strMap;
    private Person3[] p3;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setI(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void setP(Person2 p){
        this.p = p;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public int getI(){
        return this.i;
    }

    public Person2 getP(){
        return this.p;
    }

    public void setStrList(List<String> strList){
        this.strList = strList;
    }

    public List<String> getStrList(){
        return this.strList;
    }

    public void setStrMap(HashMap<String, String> strMap){
        this.strMap = strMap;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getStrMap(){
        return this.strMap;
    }

    public void setP3(Person3[] p3){
        this.p3 = p3;
    }

    public Person3[] getP3(){
        return this.p3;
    }
}
```

For e.g. currently this generates following JSON Schema, when above Person class is used as a parameter -

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "i": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "p": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "i": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "p1": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "id": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "i": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "strList": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "strMap": {
            "type": "object"
        },
        "p3": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "i": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "classname": "com.agent.Person"
}
```

Person class has some **multi-value** data structures like **MAP**, **ARRAYs** and can also have nested **POJOs**. So I wan't to generate a JSON schema for these type of **BEAN/POJO** classes and also want to put a **"classname"** node for each nested **POJO/BEAN**, having a **fully classified classname**.

I'm going through a lot of stuff for this, but I'm unable to figure out a short hand for these kind of situations using Jackson.

The requirement to be noted here is to put **"classname"** attribute in the nested POJO attribute schema.

This question definitely related to this - [How to traverse generated json schema using jackson and put custom attribute in json schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910472/how-to-traverse-generated-json-schema-using-jackson-and-put-custom-attribute-in)

Comment: give sample json to ease of understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be one of the approach for the above question could be as follows -

## Approach 1

This is my code of putting the classnames in the generated schema. This code handles the case when the an array or a non-array parameter is provided. i.e. Person.class and Person[].class can be handled successfully. This code cannot handle the self reference issue which is still open on Jackson - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/339

The code below can be instantiated as follows -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Class<?> cls = Person[].class;
        if(cls.isArray()){
            cls = cls.getComponentType();
        }
        String s = "{\"rootNode\":{\"classname\":\"" + cls.getName() + "\"},"
                + getAttributeClassnames(cls) + "}";
        s = s.replace("\",}", "\"}").replace("},}", "}}");
        System.out.println(s);
        s = mapper.generateJsonSchema(cls).getSchemaNode().put("type", "array")
                .put("classnames", s).toString();
        s = s.replace("\\", "").replace("\"{", "{").replace("}\"", "}");        
        System.out.println(s);
    }

static String getAttributeClassnames(Class<?> cls) {
    String s = "";      
        Field[] field = cls.getDeclaredFields();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < field.length) {              
            if (!(field[i].getType() == Boolean.class)
                    && !(field[i].getType() == Integer.class)
                    && !(field[i].getType() == Character.class)
                    && !(field[i].getType() == Byte.class)
                    && !(field[i].getType() == Short.class)
                    && !(field[i].getType() == Long.class)
                    && !(field[i].getType() == Float.class)
                    && !(field[i].getType() == Double.class)
                    && !(field[i].getType().isPrimitive())
                    && !(field[i].getType() == String.class)
                    && !(Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field[i]
                            .getType()))
                    && !(Map.class.isAssignableFrom(field[i].getType()))
                    && !(Arrays.class.isAssignableFrom(field[i].getType()))) {
                if(field[i].getType() == cls){
                    if (i == field.length - 1) {
                        Class<?> name = null;
                        if(field[i].getType().isArray()){
                            name = field[i].getType().getComponentType();
                        }else{
                            name = field[i].getType();
                        }
                        s = s + "\"" + field[i].getName() + "\""
                                + ":{\"classname\":\""
                                + name.getName() + "\","
                                +"}";
                    } else {
                        Class<?> name = null;                       
                        if(field[i].getType().isArray()){
                            name = field[i].getType().getComponentType();
                        }else{
                            name = field[i].getType();
                        }
                        s = s + "\"" + field[i].getName() + "\""
                                + ":{\"classname\":\""
                                + name.getName() + "\","
                                + "}" + ",";
                    }
                
                }else{
                    if (i == field.length - 1) {
                        Class<?> name = null;
                        if(field[i].getType().isArray()){
                            name = field[i].getType().getComponentType();
                        }else{
                            name = field[i].getType();
                        }
                        s = s + "\"" + field[i].getName() + "\""
                                + ":{\"classname\":\""
                                + name.getName() + "\","
                                + getAttributeClassnames(name)
                                + "}";
                    } else {
                        Class<?> name = null;                       
                        if(field[i].getType().isArray()){
                            name = field[i].getType().getComponentType();
                        }else{
                            name = field[i].getType();
                        }
                        s = s + "\"" + field[i].getName() + "\""
                                + ":{\"classname\":\""
                                + name.getName() + "\","
                                + getAttributeClassnames(name)
                                + "}" + ",";
                    }
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    return s;
}
```

## Approach 2

Other approach could be, to maintain a graph of classnames for the Jackson generated schema.

e.g.

```
"classnames":{
          "<attribute_name>":{
                                "classname":"<classname>"
                             }
}
```